Low-dimension matrix approximation?
I have a matrix $\mathbf E_1 \in \mathbb R^{m\times n_1}$. I would like to approximate it with a matrix $\mathbf E_2 \in \mathbb R^{m\times n_2}$ with $n_2 < n_1$, where "approximate" means I want to find $$\arg\min_{\mathbf E_2 \in \mathbb R^{m\times n_2}}\min_{\mathbf W\in\mathbb R^{n_2\times n_1}} || \mathbf E_1 - \mathbf E_2\mathbf W ||_F^2$$
I'm aware of low-rank approximation with SVD, but this problem is different in the sense that even a truncated SVD of $\mathbf E_1$ is still of dimension $m\times n_1$, not $m\times n_2$.
Is there a name for this new problem? If yes, is there a closed-form solution to it, like there is for low-rank approximation? The alternative is solve it with an iterative gradient-based algorithm, in which case: is this a convex optimisation problem, at least?

This is not a  convex optimization problem, due to the multiplication of $E_2$ and $W$, which are both optimization (matrix) variables.

This is just a low-rank approximation problem. You can absolutely obtain the minimizer using a truncated SVD, you just need to truncate at $n_2$ singular values. I suspect that you've confused the "truncated" and "compact" SVDs.

@BenGrossmann I don't think I have. A full SVD $E = U\Sigma V^T$ has $U \in \mathbb R^{m\times m}, \Sigma \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}, V \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. A compact SVD only keeps the non-zero singular values so that the span of the matrix (and hence null space) is preserved. Let the rank be $r$, then we drop the basis vectors of left and right null space with $U_r \in \mathbb R^{m\times r}, \Sigma_r \in \mathbb R^{r\times r}, V_r \in \mathbb R^{n\times r}$. Product stays $E$. Truncated SVD is this but with $r$ substituted for a lower number. Still $m\times n$, but approximating $E$.

@Mew But you can simply take $r=n_2$ and $E_2=U_r\Sigma_r$, $W=V_r^T$. Have I missed something?

@BenGrossmann Oh. That's actually a pretty neat suggestion. I guess because the objective is to find $E_2$, I thought that by "This is just a low-rank approximation problem." you meant that it would still be of the form $E_2 = U_r\Sigma_r V_r^T$, with $W$ something else. Now I'm also wondering if you've missed something, because that's deviously easy.

$E_2W$ is a matrix with rank at most $n_2$. Following the Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem, the smallest possible result for the objective function is obtained when $E_2 W$ is equal to the truncated SVD of $E_1$ in which all singular values besides the first $n_2$ are "zeroed out". With this in mind, it suffices to take $E_2 = U_{n_2} \Sigma_{n_2}$ and $W = V_{n_2}^T$, where $E_1 = U_{n_2}\Sigma_{n_2}V_{n_2}^T$ denotes a such a truncated SVD.

Emphasis on "it suffices". Since many matrix pairs may produce $U_{n_2}\Sigma_{n_2} V_{n_2}^T$, more constraints would be needed if we wanted to select a pair that differs from $(U_{n_2}\Sigma_{n_2}, V_{n_2}^T)$ (say, if we wanted $E_1E_1^T$ as close to $E_2 E_2^T$ as possible too).

@Mew Right. Typically, this kind of optimization would be done over the matrix $E_2 W$ itself rather than having unconstrained matrices being multiplied like this. Given an optimal $E_2, W$, for any invertible $n_2 \times n_2$ matrix $S$, $E_2' = E_2S$ and $W' = S^{-1}W$ will also be an optimal pair. You might notice that with the current scheme, the $E_1$ we select always has orthogonal columns and $W$ has orthonormal rows.

In fact, when $n_2 \leq \text{rank}(E_1)$, there are no zeroes on the diagonal of $\Sigma_{n_2}$, which would make it invertible and hence qualify as an $S$ like you said, meaning you could even just let $E_2 = U_{n_2}$.
